# If kshatriyas and vaishyas don't exist, who can take up arms and do farming?

Tags: caste-system, dharma-shastras, varna, india, varnashrama

For example, the shastra says only people born as kshatriyas and who have done upanayanam can be military or police:

> Manu 10.79 - For the Kṣatriya, carrying of arms and weapons. For the
> Vaiśya, business, rearing cattle, and agriculture are the means of
> livelihood, while giving donations, studying the Vedas and doing Vedic
> sacrifices constitute their spiritual duty.
>
> This verse is quoted in Parāśaramādhava (Ācāra, p. 397), to the effect
> that **the wielding of weapons for the protection of the weak is the
> duty of the Kṣatriya only**;—and in Mitākṣarā (1.119).

In India today, kshatriyas who have done upanayanam don't exist, or their numbers are extremely limited, and according to the shastras, only kshatriyas who have done upanayanam can take up arms. Most hindu kshatriyas today are "vratyas", or those who have stopped doing upanayanam. According to the shastras, "vratya kshatriyas" have their own duty, and it does not involve bearing arms.

This seems to suggest that modern India should not have a military or police force because they are no kshatriyas.

And likewise, modern India should not have any agricultural activities since there are no vaishyas who have done upanayanam.

And the low castes cannot take up the occupations of the higher castes:

> Vaśiṣṭha (2. 2 2-23).—‘Those who are unable to live by their own
> occupation may adopt that of the next inferior caste; but never that
> of a higher caste.’
>
> Viṣṇu (2.15).—‘In times of distress, each caste may follow the
> occupation of that next below it in rank.’
>
> Vaśiṣṭha (2.23).—‘One shall never adopt the occupation of a higher
> caste.’

How do we resolve this dilemma in modern times? If India does not have police, military, agriculture, it will cease to exist as a nation state.

Shall we say these scriptural rules are obsolete?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143130/discussion-on-question-by-ikshvaku-if-kshatriyas-and-vaishyas-dont-exist-who-c); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.